# Showing that $\mathbb{N×N×N}$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Show, by listing the elements or how we can list the elements, that

$\mathbb{N}^3$ = $\mathbb{N×N×N}$ is a countable set.

**Attempt at a solution:**

I was thinking about making use of Cantor's diagonal argument. If this were $\mathbb{N×N}$ I could just do:

(1,1), (1,2), (1,3),...

(2,1), (2,2), (2,3)...

(3,1), (3,2), (3, 3)...

and snake my way through it.

However, I am having trouble finding a way to list $\mathbb{N×N×N}$ such that I can implement the diagonal argument.

Comment: $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N\times \Bbb N=(\Bbb N\times \Bbb N)\times \Bbb N\sim \Bbb N\times\Bbb N\sim \Bbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an explicit listing of the elements of $\Bbb N^3$, you might start with all $(x,y,z)$ with $x+y+z=3$, then those with $x+y+z=4$, etc.
For each sum $s$, there are only finitely many choices of $x,y,z$ (namely $s-1\choose 2$), and these can be ordered lexically, i.e., sort by $x$, then $y$ (then $z$, but that's irrelevant). With patience, you could develop explicit formulae from this procedure to compute the $n$ triple.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I think I'll do. Out of curiosity, does showing how to count the elements (such that any element can be reached) as the question asks, actually prove countability? I have seen bijections to prove it before but wasn't sure if that's required.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S = \Bbb N$ and $T = \Bbb N \times \Bbb N \times \Bbb N$.

Then, $f:S \to T$ defined by $f(n) = (n,0,0)$ is an injection, and so is $g:T \to S$ defined by $g(n,m,k) = 2^n 3^m 5^k$.

Hence, there exists a bijection between $S$ and $T$ per [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

To go your way, $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ with $x+y+z = c$ is a finite set.  Viewed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it is a triangle.  So explain how to snake across each of these triangles (which will look remarkably like what you are doing in $\mathbb{N}^2$).

Alternatively, let $x = \cdots 0 x_{N(x)}\cdots x_2 x_1 x_0$ be $x$'s base 10 digital representation (preceded by an infinite number of zeroes so we may avoid an astounding amount of fussy notation) and similarly for $y$ and $z$.  Then consider the number $\cdots 0 \cdots x_2 y_2 z_2 x_1 y_1 z_1 x_0 y_0 z_0$ formed by interleaving the digits of $x$, $y$, and $z$...

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{N}^3$ is a countable union of finite sets:

$$\mathbb{N}^3 = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{(i,j,k)\in\mathbb{N^3} : i + j + k = n\}$$

Hence, $\mathbb{N}^3$ is countable.

For an explicit bijection:

Notice that every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written in a unique way as a product of a power of $2$, power of $3$, and a number not divisible by $2$ nor $3$.
$$n = 2^{i-1}3^{j-1}k$$

Now define $f : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N^3}$ as $f(n) = (i,j,k)$ to get the bijection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already found an explicit bijection $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$
defined by
$f(n)\mapsto(g(n), h(n)),$
you can extend this to a bijection 
$k:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$
by setting 
$$
k(n)=(g(n), g(h(n)), h(h(n))).
$$
You can recursively apply this technique as many times as desired to get a bijection to the cross product of any number of copies of  $\mathbb N.$